# Comparing Values of 2 dictionaries in Python and Constructing New dictionary From Comparison

Tags: python, dictionary, compare, iteration

I am using Python 2.7.4.  I am trying to compare values from two different dictionaries in python and construct a new dictionary based upon the results of the comparison.
my users input the post positions and mlodds1 and tbodds1 of horses into 3 lists then I do the following:

```
ml_dict = dict(zip(postpositions,mlodds1))
tb_dict = dict(zip(postpositions,tbodds1))
```

to construct two dictionaries from those lists.
I want a new dictionary: `screened_dict[a,x]` to be made of the value x < y in tb_dict[a,x] and ml_dict(a, y).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want here.  Could you maybe provide a simple example of `ml_dict` and `tb_dict` and then what you would like `screened_dict` to be?

Comment: Sure. postpositions = (1,2,3...8), the morning line odds are set by pro handicappers.  These odds, mlodds1 are input as a number by the user in my program into a list mlodds1 (2.5,4,6,8,10,15,20,25) which represent the odds 5/2, 4/1, etc for each horse post position.  The toteboard odds tbodds1 are input as a list of the actual odds from the toteboard at the track it may be a list like (3,2,6,8,9,15,20,30) the dictionaries are then ml_dict  = {1:2.5,2:4,3:6,4:8,5:10,6:15,7:20,8:25} and tb_dict = {1:3,2:2,3:6,4:8,5:9,6:15,7:20,8:30}  then screened_dict = {2:2,5:9,} in this particular example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
combined = {}
for x in ml_dict:
    try:
        if tb_dict[x] < ml_dict[x]: combined[x] = ml_dict[x]
    except KeyError: continue
```

Comment: Here's how I implemented it:for x in ml_dict:
 try:
  if tb_dict[x] < ml_dict[x]: combined[x] = tb_dict[x]
 except KeyError: continue
print 'These horses odds have dropped:', combined